# Passing path variable from powershell x86 to python doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have been routinely running a python script using Windows PowerShell. I have recently made changes to the code and now it doesn't seem to work. 
To elaborate, there is an issue with the variable 'root_dir_path' being passed from powershell to python.

In powershell I run the following which should define the path variable 'root_dir_path':

```
PS Z:\> C:\Hyapp\FIJI-W~1.52P\Fiji.app\ImageJ-win64.exe --ij2 --headless -- 
console --run D:\Cabut- 
PWP1-preliminary-data\All\great_grandpa\stitcher-GREAT-grandpa-pro-2.0.py 
"root_dir_path='D:\Cabut- 
PWP1-preliminary-data\All\Stitching'"
```

Please could somebody tell me why it subsequently doesn't work?

Particularly giving the following error:

```
    NameError: name 'root_dir_path' is not defined
```

And the line in question (361) is when I am trying to call the main() function:

```
main(root_dir_path)
```

I get the following in powershell:

```
PS Z:\> C:\Hyapp\FIJI-W~1.52P\Fiji.app\ImageJ-win64.exe --ij2 --headless --console --run D:\Cabut- 
PWP1-preliminary-data\All\great_grandpa\stitcher-GREAT-grandpa-pro-2.0.py "root_dir_path='D:\Cabut- 
PWP1-preliminary-data\All\Stitching'"
PS Z:\> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=128m; support was removed 
in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be 
removed in a future release
tammikuuta 31, 2020 5:21:04 IP. java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows 
RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
[WARNING] Unmatched input: root_dir_path
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Cabut-PWP1-preliminary-data\All\great_grandpa\stitcher-GREAT-grandpa-pro-2.0.py", line 362, 
in <module>
main(root_dir_path)
NameError: name 'root_dir_path' is not defined

    at org.python.core.Py.NameError(Py.java:290)
    at org.python.core.PyFrame.getname(PyFrame.java:257)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(D:\Cabut-PWP1-preliminary-data\All\great_grandpa\stitcher-GREAT-grandpa-pro-2.0.py:362)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(D:\Cabut-PWP1-preliminary-data\All\great_grandpa\stitcher-GREAT-grandpa-pro-2.0.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:171)
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
    at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1614)
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.eval(__builtin__.java:497)
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.eval(__builtin__.java:501)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.eval(PythonInterpreter.java:259)
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:57)
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:31)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at org.scijava.script.ScriptModule.run(ScriptModule.java:160)
    at org.scijava.module.ModuleRunner.run(ModuleRunner.java:168)
    at org.scijava.module.ModuleRunner.call(ModuleRunner.java:127)
    at org.scijava.module.ModuleRunner.call(ModuleRunner.java:66)
    at org.scijava.thread.DefaultThreadService.lambda$wrap$2(DefaultThreadService.java:228)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally.

The call for the main function in the python script also had the following line above:

```
#@String root_dir_path
main(root_dir_path)
```

This `#@String root_dir_path` seemed to be necessary for the variable to pass correctly from powershell. When I had reformatted automatically in pycharm a space was added as it thought this line was a simple comment:

```
# @String root_dir_path
```

This seemed to cause the error. Getting rid of the space allowed it to work once more.